# Lightbox for Flex

Tags: image, apache-flex, gallery, lightbox

Ey. I've seen the other post about Lightbox gallery effect for Flex, but after having played around with it I cant seem to get it to work 100% (The image is as small as the thumb, and I cant make it bigger). And this also lacks some functionality I'd like to have.

So, one example would be, of course, this: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
If you click any image on the image set you can swap between them with an arrow. This is what I'd like to have.

Also, it would be nice if it was possible to display the thumbnails for the other images in the same set under the bigger picture(when one image is already clicked).

I've tried to search for components like this, but I cant seem to find any other.

If any of you know of any nice components or snippets of code for this kind of effect then please let me know! =)

Kind regards,
Stian Berg Larsen

**EDIT:**

---

So I've searched around and tried a number of examples, but I cant seem to get any of them to work. There is always an error, and none of the examples are exactly what I want.

I simply need a way to show images like Lightbox. With a prev/next arrow and maybe a close button. Nothing more than that. How would I go about making this, or use an existing component?

Im using a TileGroup to hold all my thumbs (so that they will fill out the width of the Group with more images if there are room for it). If it's possible to generate this list of thumbnails dynamically too then that would be great, but basically what I need is to show images with a Lightbox style when I click them.

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just making my own lightbox effect. :)

Created an Actionscript class (based on Group) and added image loading functionality, prev/next/close buttons and borders and such. Works like a charm :)